# What does '-' denote in version sequence?

Tags: linux, package, archlinux

I am working with archlinux packages and their version information. I encountered some packages with version of the form 1.4.1.6-1 what does '-1' exactly mean in this version sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value after the - is the release. It differentiates between different releases of a package that have the same version. It's used for e.g. security patches to an existing version of the software.